# How to set @XmlType.namespace via JAXB External Bindings Customization file

Tags: java, jaxb

I am using JAXB to process multiple XML documents.

My issue is that I cannot change the related xsd's and I don't want to amend the generated classes.

What I want to do is employ JAXB Binding customization files to achieve the desired result.

All I need to do is perform the equivalent of using the `@XmlType.namespace` annotation.

Is it possible to set the `@XmlType.namespace` annotation via JAXB Binding Customization files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of the [`jaxb2-annotate-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin).

You can use the [`jaxb2-annotate-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin) to add arbitrary annotations to your schema-derived classes. `@XmlType` will be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc annox"
    version="2.1">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='someType']">
            <annox:annotateClass>@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType(namespace="urn:test")</annox:annotateClass>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

If you already have an `@XmlType` there, the customized annotation will be "merged" into it.

Comment: lexicore, thanks for taking the time to look at this. It does sound like jaxb2 plugin will resolve my issue, however i cannot get past this error [ERROR] Unsupported binding namespace "http://annox.dev.java.net". I am using Eclipse LUNA to generate the JAXB files. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added and activated the `jaxb2-annotate-plugin`? Please see the [docs](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin#using-jaxb2-annotate-plugin-with-maven).

Comment: I have added the jaxb2 jars to my build/run path. however I am not using MAVEN. I am using the Generate option from within Eclipse LUNA (e.g. right click on XSD's and select Generate > JAXB Classes...) , how do I activate jaxb2 when generating JAXB classes from within Eclipse?

Comment: @Hector I don't know at the moment. I'll check and let you know. Try to find an option to add and activate JAXB plugin there. And please ask this as an extra question ("How to generate JAXB classes in Eclipse using additional JAXB plugins"), maybe someone already knows the answer.

Comment: asked a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817501/how-to-generate-jaxb-classes-in-eclipse-using-additional-jaxb-plugins