# How to generate JAXB classes in Eclipse using additional JAXB plugins

Tags: java, jaxb2

I am using Eclipse LUNA to generate JAXB Classes.

I am attempting to employ the `jaxb2-annotate-plugin` to add arbitrary annotations to my schema-derived classes.

My restrictions are that I cannot change the related xsd's and I don't want to amend the generated classes.

how do I activate jaxb2 when generating JAXB classes from within Eclipse?

All I need to do is perform the equivalent of using the `@XmlType.namespace` annotation.

I am right clicking on my xsd file, selecting Generate > JAXB Classes...

I cannot get past this error [ERROR] Unsupported binding namespace `"annox.dev.java.net";.`

Comment: @closer It's not too broad, it is quite specific.